# Maximal chain of primes in a finitely generated $\mathbb C$-algebra

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, krull-dimension

> Let $A=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/\langle xyz-1\rangle$. Find a maximal chain of primes in $A$.

I think it has to do something with the Krull dimension but I don't really know how to construct such a chain. Can you please give me a detailed example for such?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 0):

You could think geometrically:

$xyz=1$ is an irreducible hypersurface in $\mathbb A_{\mathbb C}^3$. A maximal chain of primes in $A$ corresponds to a chain of the form

$$\text{surface} \supset \text{curve} \supset \text{point}$$

So, we are looking for a curve on this hypersurface. The easiest way to obtain such a curve is to look at the intersection with another hypersurface, say $x=1$. This gives rise to the curve $yz=1$ in the plane given by $x=1$. This curve corresponds to the prime ideal $(x-1,yz-1)$ and indeed we have $xyz-1=yz(x-1)+(yz-1) \in (x-1,yz-1)$.

Now we are looking for a point on that curve. That is a no-brainer, take $x=y=z=1$, corresponding to the ideal $(x-1,y-1,z-1)$.

Summing up, we have found the chain

$$(xyz-1) \subset (x-1,yz-1) \subset (x-1,y-1,z-1)$$